# When and where are the "shape" and weights of a keras / tensorflow layer determined and stored?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Two concrete questions:

Why doesn't a keras `Dense` layer know its `input_shape` and `output_shape`, even after the model is run?

Why doesn't the layer know its parameter count until some training data is pumped through?

I train a simple keras / tensorflow model, but when I attempt to look at the model's layers I get errors such as:

> "AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape."

Or, the short version of my questions:  What is going on here?

I'm sure that in some technical sense "the layer has never been called" and "has no defined input shape," but, since the layer has been trained (and used for evaluation), what does it mean that it "has never been called"?

(What I really need is an overview -- I haven't it found yet -- of keras's architecture and an accessible introduction to what is going on under the hood.  Hello keras gurus!)

Specifically, I run the first model from the tensorflow tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/

Here is the tutorial sample code that I ran:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

After running (i.e., constructing, compiling, fitting, and evaluating) the model, I call, for example:

```py
model.layers[1].input_shape
```

and get:

> File "\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", l ine 1338, in input_shape
>       raise AttributeError('The layer has never been called '
>   AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.

In a related vein, if, before running`model.fit()`, but after running `model.compile()`, I call:

```py
model.layers[1].count_params()
```

I get:

> ValueError: You tried to call `count_params` on dense_3, but the layer isn't built. You can build it manually via: `dense_3.build(batch_input_shape)`.

If I call `count_params()` after calling `model.fit()` I get 401920.  (Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions.)  (This value is equal to 785 x 512 -- I would have expected 784 x 512, but I suppose that's close enough ...)

Naively I might have supposed that "compiling" a model sets up the various data structures containing the model parameters to be optimized, but, rather, it looks like this happens on the fly when you first pump a round of training data through the model.

Okay, but what, then, does `model.compile()` do?

(This is using tensorflow 1.12.0 with python 3.7.2 on windows.)

Comment: I am guessing that this has to do with Lazy Evaluation. The len does not function like a list in Python. When you create a list it is immediately stored in memory and Python knows how big it is. With certain things that are lazily evaluated, outside of simple generators, Python may not know ahead of fitting or counting params how many exist. I'll let someone else elaborate on this, but I'm almost certain `lazy evaluation` is your culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TensorFlow, tensors have [two different types](https://blog.metaflow.fr/shapes-and-dynamic-dimensions-in-tensorflow-7b1fe79be363) of shapes: a *dynamic shape* and a *static shape*. Consider the static and dynamic shapes of a tensor named `my_tensor`.

The static shape is only available if you define it while creating a tensor of if it can be inferred from other tensors in the graph with defined shapes. If defined, it can be found using `my_tensor.get_shape()` at any time.

The dynamic shape is only available at runtime and must be commensurate with the static shape. At runtime, a node can be added to the graph that returns a tensor containing the dynamic shape using `tf.shape`  i.e. write `my_shape=tf.shape(my_tensor)` and run the `my_shape` node in your session.

Comment: Jeffrey -  Thanks; first clarifying question:  Am I right that the batch size is part of the shape, so that the dynamic shape only becomes determined when I run `model.fit()` (which uses a default batch size of 32).  Is this part of the reason that shape isn't known even after I've built (and compiled) the model?  (As an aside, might it be possible for `model.fit()` to use different batch sizes within a single run so that the shape wouldn't be constant even for a single run?)

Comment: Jeffrey -  Second clarifying question:  How do I link your answer about tensorflow tensors and things like `tf.shape` to the keras world I am working in?  I do not imagine that a keras layer (or, to be concrete, a keras `Dense`) is a tensor, per se.  That is, how do I relate something like `layer[1].input_shape` (even if it is dynamic, and not (yet) defined) to something like your `tf.shape(my_tensor)`?

Comment: Jeffrey -  Third clarifying question:  I am starting to think that the weights in a layer are not, in the formal keras / tensorflow sense, a tensor (but, rather, some other data structure).  Instead, tensors are the blobs of data that flow from one layer to another.  Is this correct, or am I all wet here?

Comment: In order: 1) The static shape can be partially defined. Defining the batch size means that this dimension can be inferred, restricting the dynamic shape. However, the full shape is not known. Answering your aside: it is possible to use different batch sizes throughout training, either by using a custom data pipeline that does not define the batch dimension of the static shape or, depending on the function, by using a [placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) for the batch size.

Comment: 2) If you are using Keras with TensorFlow as a backend, you can use them interchangeably. You can also use them together with other deep learning libraries e.g. [Sonnet](https://github.com/deepmind/sonnet). Layers are just functions. Typically, if they act on a tensor, they return a tensor e.g. `output_tensor = keras_layer(**layer_params)(input_tensor)`.

Comment: 3) Weight/biases are tensors. They are part of the layer and are applied to tensors input to the layer by the layer function. For example, a convolutional layer will apply a kernels' weights by convolving them across the input tensor to produce an output.

Comment: 3 cont.) You're correct: The blocks of numbers outputted by layers are tensors, as are all the weights/biases. "A [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) is a geometric object that maps in a multi-linear manner geometric vectors, scalars, and other tensors to a resulting tensor."

Comment: Jeffrey -  Re: your 2)  That is very helpful for me to understand layers as functions that (typically) map a tensor to a tensor.

Comment: Jeffrey -  Re: your 3)  Would you happen to know in my concrete example how to display the shape of the `Dense` weights tensor (after `model.fit()` has been run so the weights have, in fact, been populated)?

Answer (score 0):

I see that the tutorial code I linked to and cited
has been modified to include `input_shape` in the
`Flatten` layer.  It now reads:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

(The link remains https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials)

This update to the code partially answers my question.